# Erase Old Spark Structured Streaming Event-Time Windows

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I am getting aggregated data in event-time windows, but the data I need is the one contained in the newest 3 windows. What would be the right way to erase the other processed older windows I don need?

```
val query = lines
  .withWatermark("timestamp", "20 seconds")
  .groupBy(window($"timestamp", "10 seconds"),$"value").count().sort(-$"window")
  .writeStream
  .outputMode("complete")
  .format("console")
  .start()
```

I would like to see only the last 3 newest windows. Would filtering out the windows older than 30 seconds good enough?

Thanks